# Bind DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to a nested List

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a class with the following properties:

```
Public string Name { get; set; }
Public string LastName { get; set; }
Public List<string> Jobs{ get; set; }
```

The properties `Name` and `LastName` are bound to a `DataGridView`, while I need to bind `Jobs` to a `ComboBox` inside the `DataGridView`.

- If the person has 1 job in the `ComboBox` it should appear with only the number 1.
- If the person has 2 jobs it should appear with 1 and 2 when clicking on the `ComboBox`.

For example:

```
John Smith 1
Paul Mayer 1
           2
```

Here is how I'm adding the `ComboBoxColumn`:

```
private void AddComboBox()
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Jobs = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    foreach (var item in People)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < item.Jobs.Count; i++)
        {
            Jobs.Items.Add(item.Jobs[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

But this code makes every `ComboBox` the same, so instead of having 1 in the first and 1-2 in the second `ComboBox`, I get 1-1-2 for each `ComboBox`.

Is there a way to get the current `ComboBox` for adding items? Unfortunately, since it is a `ComboBoxColumn` I don't have the `Rows[i]` property like the cells.

I also tried with a databinding but `Jobs` is a list so `DataPropertyName` throws an error due to the conversion from list to string.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Could you please post your code where the data binding happens?

Answer (score 1):

You can use data binding by sourcing each `ComboBox` after the `DataGridView` has completed its own source binding.

1. Remove `AddComboBox` completely, you won't be needing it.
2. Add the following event handler, `dataGridViewJobs.DataBindingComplete += DataGridViewJobs_DataBindingComplete;` and within it source each `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`:

   ```
   private void DataGridViewJobs_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
   {
       string colName = "Jobs";

       if (dataGridViewJobs.Columns.Contains(colName))
       {
           dataGridViewJobs.Columns.Remove(colName);
       }

       DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
       column.Name = colName;
       dataGridViewJobs.Columns.Add(column);

       foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewJobs.Rows)
       {
           var person = (Person)row.DataBoundItem;
           var cell = row.Cells[colName] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;

           cell.DataSource = person.Jobs;
           cell.Value = person.Jobs[0];
       }
   }
   ```